# How to catch data from gui

Tags: javascript, user-interface, web, go, webview

I'm coding simple app and I use Golang for this purpose. Nowadays there's no exact way to create GUI, so I have to load one of libs - [webview](https://github.com/zserge/webview). So as far as I understood, I can trigger actions from front-end using JS `external.invoke('eventName')`.

Also I can push data from back- to front-end using Go

``` simpleJS := ``console.log("`` + myVar + ``")
 w.Eval(simpleJS) ```

(there ` should not be doubled)

So the question is how can I get data from JS. As I understand trigger have only its name, not more. As closest probable solution I decided to stringify wrap of eventName + data and parse it on Backend

Comment: The examples appear to send JSON through  `external.invoke`: https://github.com/zserge/webview/blob/master/examples/todo-go/assets/app.js#L40

Comment: @Adrian ah, seems I did same. But thank for point